# ASP.NET MVC 4 WebSecurity Seed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I have some simple DbContext:

```
public class AuthContext : DbContext
{
    public AuthContext() : base("AuthContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And simple User model:

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is to seed data to WebSecurity always or after model creating. I have tried:

```
    Database.SetInitializer(new AuthDbSeeder());
```

//--------------------------------------------------------

```
    <add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ChatAuth; Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and in `<system.web>` I added:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

//--------------------------------------------------------

```
public class AuthDbSeeder : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AuthContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(AuthContext context)
    {       
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("AuthContext", "User", "UserId", "Login",
                                                         autoCreateTables: true);
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("Sergey", "1234");
```

But after all I have error that Database can't be droped because it is already in use. I need some working method to seed data to WebSecurity.
Also very important for me is: how I can add my custom models in the same DbContext and seed data to this context properly.

Also any ideas how I can Unit test WebSecurity?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution for the seed question

I reworked SimpleMembershipInitializer:

```
        private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("AuthContext", "User", "UserId", "Login",
                                                             autoCreateTables: true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

And in my seed method call

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref initializer, ref isInitialized, ref initializerLock);
    }
```

with null as the parameter.

Unit testing is still a problem

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example on how to seed and customize WebSecurity here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).